# How to deserialize from a file to different class

Tags: java, file, serialization, package, deserialization

I serialize a `ArrayList<packageA.Changelog> list` to a file and transmitted the file to another system in another machine.

And since it's a different system that received the file, I don't have the same `packageA.Changelog` class, instead is a `packageB.Changelog` which has exactly same structure but in different package.

And when I use

`ArrayList<packageB.Changelog> changelogs = (ArrayList<packageB.Changelog>)ois.readObject();`

to read out from the file I got a `ClassCastException`.

How to avoid this exception? Do I need to create the same package structure in the other system only for receiving the list?

Comment: usually serilized objects are primitive data types.What are you holding in the list.try to seralize all objects inside arraylist and try.

Comment: The fields in the class Changelog is only some Strings and Dates,but in the String of data may contain some XML structure, so I try to serialize the whole class to avoid escaping special characters.

Comment: @Gustly: what are you talking about? Serialization can **definitely** write reference types.

Comment: For serialization you can use XStream (http://xstream.codehaus.org/) library. It is way more flexible than standard java serialization. In your case you could add @XStreamAlias annotations to your class on both sides and overcome problems with different class names.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there are one of the three things you can do.

1. Create the same class with the same package name
2. Create an interface(ofcourse again in the same package on both the machines) and ship it on client machines. All your classes can implement this interface even in different packages. For example, your interface can be named Loggable and it should have all the methods declared which are in ChangeLog class right now.
3. Or finally instead of using the class "ChangeLog" just completely avoid using it and use a HashMap instead which is serializable by default. And you will not have to ship anything to your client(other) machine. You will be able to serialize ArrayList and convert it back to object on other machine.

All the Classes which implement class Loggable can then cast to that type.
I hope this helps

Comment: Thank you! I will choose the third method, because the Changelog class is simple enough to do so.

Comment: #2 is not correct. The actual class being serialised must be present at the target. Using interfaces does it eliminate this constraint.

Answer (score -3):

> I don't have the same `packageA.Changelog` class, instead is a `packageB.Changelog` which has exactly same structure but in different package.

Why? *This* is the problem. Don't do that.

Comment: These are two independent programs which try to collaborate.

Comment: @Paŭlo Ebermann No, they aren't independent. You are trying to serialize data from one to the other. So they need shared classes to do that with.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but your answer could be a bit more detailed - e.g. adding the information from comment (responding to mine) would help. As it is, it only says "having a same-named class in different packages is a bad idea", which neither is true nor answers the question.

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann I didn't say it was a 'bad idea'. I said it *causes the problem.* That is by any definition an answer. It is also *true,* which makes it a *correct* answer. Downvoting correct answers doesn't make any sense to me, and leaving no explanation ditto.