# Dropwizard: Microservice Architecture

Tags: dropwizard, microservices

This is similar to [How to deserialize from a file to different class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6994054/how-to-deserialize-from-a-file-to-different-class). But, I'm developing micro-services using Dropwizard.

I have two services, service A and service B. I have a message queue (RabbitMQ) setup between the two services.

I am trying to send an object of type Class A (defined in service A) from service A to service B. I have not imported class A in service B. However in service B i have Class B defined which is exactly same as Class A.

I am getting a ClassNotFoundException: Class A in service B when service B tries to deserialize and typecast the object to Class B.

I want the two jars to be as independent as possible. 
Is there a way to do this.

Comment: do you use XML, JSON, ...?

Comment: nope. I de serialize the object using ObjectOuputStream in service A and serialize it back using ObjectinputStream on service B. In short, the message is sent in the form of a byte array.

Comment: Why do you feel the need to avoid consuming Class A into Service B. It's just a data contract.

Comment: Yeah, I understand, but that would create a dependency right?

Comment: Say, I add a new service, Service C to this, and some data/object is sent to Service C from Service A or Service B, I need to consume that too. Would it not bloat the services and increase the dependency between them. So what I am trying to get at is, is there a way for the micro services to communicate with each other without knowing each others existence?

Comment: @NPrakash you are right about increased coupling between services in case you introduce mentioned dependencies. If possible, avoid this kind of dependencies.  About the problem, I am no expert on deserializing objects, but have you thought of using JSON perhaps? Sending object serialized as JSON and then recieving it and deserializing it.

Comment: Oh ok, I can take that route. Wanted to know if rabbitMQ itself had a option/feature of sending/tagging a message definition along with the message, to avoid the dependency or something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **[Apache Avro](http://avro.apache.org/docs/current/gettingstartedjava.html)** for serializing (predefined avro schema) your objects between two service or if you want to use a queue bewteen them. On top you will lower the needed network bytes, because apache avro serialization is really good.

You can also use CatainProto or ProtoBuffer, but I like the apache avro method.

Comment: Thank you. Would probably used apache avro too. Please let know if you could recommend any website to get started.

Comment: @NPrakash https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.7.7/gettingstartedjava.html to get you started.