# What class is serialized behind reference

Tags: java, oop, serialization

My goal is to optimize size of serialized data. I have e.g. "small" class A:

```
class A implements Serializable {

    int a;

    public A(){
        a = 1;
    }

}
```

and "bigger" class B which extends A:

```
class B extends A implements Serializable {

    int b;

    public B(){
        b = 1;
    }

}
```

.

```
A a = new B(); // Here I create instance of B with A-type reference (is this step I have to create instance of B, not A)

//Now I want to serialize ONLY data which are from class A, not B.

sendObject(a); //Send data only as A object
```

Would this code somehow work and how can I achieve my goal?

Comment: I'm not I understand what you're asking here.  You want to serialize a `B`, but not have it serialize any data defined in the class `B`, but rather only data defined in its super class?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Send data only from super class A, no variables from B.

Comment: This is a bit like asking to extract your parent's DNA, but not yours. There's only one object here - the instance of `B` - you can only serialize the whole thing, or nothing.

Comment: This feels a bit like an [XYProblem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  What are you trying to accomplish by partially serializing an object?

Comment: You could declare a (copy-) constructor for `A`, `public A(A other) {..}`, use it to copy all relevant fields, then you can extract the data `B b=something();  A a=new A(b);` and serialize `a` ..

Comment: Even if you could only partially serialize a `B`, how would you reconstruct it from incomplete data?

Comment: I know I can serialize the whole thing, but in my real situation, there are many redundant variables which I don't want to send over network. I am trying to find some easy trick to solve this, not extract every single variable from super class.

Comment: Thanks for answers, I will try @Daniele

Comment: @azurefrog I want to reconstruct it just to A type, not B.

Comment: I'd suggest taking a look at [How to deserialize from a file to a different Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6994054/how-to-deserialize-from-a-file-to-different-class).  It sounds like you're asking about a specific subset of that problem.